# smtp envelope "from" vs. message header From:

Tags: smtp

What is the difference in semantics between the smtp envelope "from" (e.g. `MAIL FROM:<billg@microsoft.com>` and the `From:` header field in the message itself?

Is there a legitimate reason (other than something shady like spam or exploits) for these to differ?

Answer (score 3):

The `smtp.mailfrom` or envelope from is the address used in the `Return-Path` header. As the name of the header somewhat suggests, this address is used for automatic response, e.g. bounces.

Many third party systems for marketing email or transactional email use a different `Retrun-Path` address, for the bounce-handling feature, where bounced addresses are taken out of the mailing list, often to preserve reputation.

Another reason to use a different Return-Path is the 10-lookup limit in `SPF` (as `SPF` is checked on the `Return-Path` address. Preferably by using a domain that shares the organizational domain used in the `Header.From` address, to preserve domain alignment (important for DMARC).

Answer (score 1):

One of legitimate reasons for **slight** difference between envelope sender (smtp level) and header sender may be [VERP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verp)